# Powershell command to know duration of the running VM

Tags: azure

Is there any PowerShell command to know the duration for which Azure VM has been running?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Get-VM PowerShell cmdlet to see uptime.

Here are some other cmdlets you might be interested in when using Hyper-V

http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/10-awesome-hyper-v-cmdlets/

Comment: i need a command specifically for Azure VM. When i execute command Get-AzureVM i do not get any field such as "uptime".

Comment: If these were windows servers, you could use the PowerShell remoting feature to run a PowerShell script to determine your server uptime.